# CasperJS cannot access the anchor tags without using href attribute from DOM

Tags: casperjs

I have been working on CasperJS and I'm facing this problem.
    I'm able to access form elements like "document.form[0].whatever",but I'm not able to do that with anchor tags .For example "document.link[0].click" does not work.Please post your suggestions if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].click();
```

Also, casper has a convenient [`click()`](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.click) method you may want to use instead:

```
casper.start('http://foo', function() {
    this.click('a');
}).run();
```